Submission of a manuscript to two special issues of the same journal
I have noticed that the content of my paper is in the scope of two special issues of a journal. Is it reasonable to submit that to both of them at the same time, or do I have to wait for the result of the first one?

Are both special issues for the same journal? Or, at least, for the same publisher?

They belong to Same journal

Though once ordinary, some publishing practices have led to some very questionable "special issues" so I would be a bit wary that you're not looking at one of these. https://retractionwatch.com/2024/01/26/springer-nature-journal-pulls-nearly-three-dozen-papers-from-special-issues/ https://retractionwatch.com/2023/03/09/wiley-paused-hindawi-special-issues-amid-quality-problems-lost-9-million-in-revenue/ https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2023/03/30/guest-post-of-special-issues-and-journal-purges/

Most (all?) reputable journals strongly (strongly) frown on duplicate submissions. Among other things, you waste the time of both editors and reviewers of at least one of them. I strongly suggest not doing this.
Instead, choose the journal (or issue) that you think is either most appropriate or might be most receptive.
If the editors of the issues are field experts for the issue, rather than publisher staff, you might contact them asking about the appropriateness of your paper prior to submission. You might get a response, but it isn't guaranteed. It might help with your decision.

Additionally, if the editors find out that you have double submitted, they might notify the other team, and you could get your submission pulled from both for policy violations. This could hinder future submissions. Better to contact them, and choose the best one as @Buffy suggests, than risk anything.

Are you aware of even a single journal that only “strongly frowns” on simultaneous submissions? The ones that I’m aware of all forbid it explicitly.

If indeed the paper would fit equally well into both Special Issues you can also think of what community you would most like to be aware of the publication (because of electronic publishing and searches this decision is not super-critical, though)

Assuming it is the same journal, you might want

to contact the editor and ask how to proceed, similar to what you did here.
submit it to one special issue and mention in the submission process that you would be also okay to be moved to the other special issue

